# Removing allowable whitespace in PHP using parser tokens

Tags: php, whitespace, minify, token

I am trying to make a simple script that will remove all unnecessary whitespace from a PHP file/string.

I have been successful at parsing the string using tokens, but don't see a good method to remove "extra" whitespace.

For instance,

```
function test() { return TRUE; }
```

should be

```
function test(){return TRUE;}
```

and NOT

```
functiontest(){returnTRUE;}
```

You end up with the last version if you just remove the T_WHITESPACE token.

Is there something I am missing to remove whitespace, but keep spaces after things like "function " and "return ". Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$newSource = '';
foreach (token_get_all($source) as $i => $token) {
    if (!is_array($token)) {
        $newSource .= $token;
    }

    if ($token[0] == T_WHITESPACE) {
        if (   isset($tokens[$i - 1])      && isset($tokens[$i + 1])
            && is_array($tokens[$i - 1])   && is_array($tokens[$i + 1])
            && isLabel($tokens[$i - 1][1]) && isLabel($tokens[$i + 1][1])
        ) {
            $newSource .= ' ';
        }
    } else {
        $newSource .= $token[1];
    }
}

function isLabel($str) {
    return preg_match('~^[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]+$~', $str);
}
```

Removing the whitespace is always allowed, apart from the case where there is a `LABEL` on both sides of it. I check that and either add nothing or a single space character.

There is just another special case I know about, there whitespace is of importance: `T_END_HEREDOC` must be followed by either `;` or `\n`. Compacting or stripping the space here is not allowed. So, if that is of importance to you, you can simply add that ;)

Comment: the script works great, thank you. It is working alongside a variable replacer as well. I running two loops on the tokens, first to catch variables, then this is in the second loop to remove whitespace, and then I replace variables. I also am removing comments, and found that if I attempt to do that in just one loop, there is a space remaining where the comment used to be. In my case, I moved it to the first loop, and all is solved.

Comment: *I found that this worked on a number of my files except for "case" statements. For instance one of my statements was checking http statuses, and "case 404:" was turned into "case404:" which is obviously an error. I just made that else an elseif($token[0]==T_CASE) { $new_source .= $token[1].' ';} (adding a space after the token) and proceeded with the current else statement in place after that.

Comment: @Matt Gaidica: Yes, my fault. I checked for what the PHP lexer defines as a `{LABEL}`, but I should have looked for numbers too, because they can occur in labels too (apart from the first character). I adjusted the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `T_WHITESPACE` can be spaces or newlines, etc. So one trivial approach would be to automatically replace all `T_WHITESPACE` instances with a new one that consists of exactly one space.

But for a smarter method, just go through the [list of parser tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php), and figure out which ones should have a whitespace after it and which should not (something like this):

```
foreach ($tokens as $k => $val) {
    if (is_array($val) && $val[0] == T_WHITESPACE) {
        if (!is_array($tokens[$k - 1])) {
            //remove this space
        } else {
            switch ($tokens[$k - 1][0]) {
                case T_ABSTRACT:
                case T_FUNCTION:
                //.. other keeps here:
                   continue;
                   break;
                default:
                    //remove the space
             }
         }
    }
}
```

And one more note, don't do this for performance.  If you're using an OPCODE Cache (Such as APC) you'll see no benefit for a lot of work.  If you're not using one, why aren't you?

Comment: Thanks for this. That was the method I was thinking I might have to do, kind of a pain! I have had the single space option going, but its kind of half-a*sing the goal.

Comment: @Matt: I really have to ask though, **why** are you doing this?  What's the goal and the justification for the goal?

Comment: Pretty much an academic exercise. I re-use my methods a lot in random places, sometimes its nice if they take up a single line. I realize this has no real ramifications to speed/execution.

Comment: @Matt: ok, fair enough.  Still not a great idea (copy-pasting, etc).  It'd be better to use a library and include the functionality rather than duplicate it.  But as an academic exercise, I guess anything goes...

Answer (score 1):

Your effort is futile.

```
php -w
```

Allows already to strip whitespace off scripts. It uses a bit more elaborate logic to remove whitespace from the token stream.
Here's the `zend_strip()` function as found in `zend_highlight.c`:

```
while ((token_type=lex_scan(&token TSRMLS_CC))) {
    switch (token_type) {
        case T_WHITESPACE:
            if (!prev_space) {
                zend_write(" ", sizeof(" ") - 1);
                prev_space = 1;
            }
                    /* lack of break; is intentional */
        case T_COMMENT:
        case T_DOC_COMMENT:
            token.type = 0;
            continue;

        case T_END_HEREDOC:
            zend_write(LANG_SCNG(yy_text), LANG_SCNG(yy_leng));
            efree(token.value.str.val);
            /* read the following character, either newline or ; */
            if (lex_scan(&token TSRMLS_CC) != T_WHITESPACE) {
                zend_write(LANG_SCNG(yy_text), LANG_SCNG(yy_leng));
            }
            zend_write("\n", sizeof("\n") - 1);
            prev_space = 1;
            token.type = 0;
            continue;

        default:
            zend_write(LANG_SCNG(yy_text), LANG_SCNG(yy_leng));
            break;
    }

    if (token.type == IS_STRING) {
        switch (token_type) {
            case T_OPEN_TAG:
            case T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO:
            case T_CLOSE_TAG:
            case T_WHITESPACE:
            case T_COMMENT:
            case T_DOC_COMMENT:
                break;

            default:
                efree(token.value.str.val);
                break;
        }
    }
    prev_space = token.type = 0;
}
```

Comment: @nikic: It's actually misleading. The `-w` option is supposed to `Output source with stripped comments and whitespace.` - but it mostly just compacts them. As example it's interesting though.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the php -w command. Futile may be a bit over-dramatic, I just want a one-click function to strip away things I don't need, and replace variables. Thank you for that reference, interesting.